# Cannot make THREE.FBXLoader locate the texture folder

Tags: directory, three.js, http-status-code-404, textures, loader

I have an FBX model imported in Three.js, and it has four textures. The model and the textures would all load well, provided that the textures are all in the same folder as the FBX file. I managed to transfer the FBX file to an assets folder, and the `FBXLoader` of the following code could easily locate it. However, upon transferring the four textures into the assets folder, I receive a **404 error**. I have also already tried the `THREE.LoadingManager()` to no avail. Here's the code:

```
const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
loader.setResourcePath(assetPath);
loader.setPath(assetPath);

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
texture = textureLoader.load(assetPath);
   ...
loader.load('model.fbx',
...
tex => {
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:tex });
progress => ...
error => ...
}
```

Rest assured that I have used the most recent libraries and dependencies. I would appreciate if anyone could help me where I am doing it wrong and assist me in loading the textures from the assets folder.

Comment: Can you please try it by just using `setResourcePath()` (and not `setPath()`)?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I've just tested it. Once I remove the `setPath()` line, even the model itself disappears and I receive this error in the console: `GET http://localhost:8080/model.fbx 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: If, currently, there is no way to do this directly in code, how could one manipulate the FBXLoader so as to achieve the expected result (keeping the textures in their own folder)?

Comment: Like so: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d4f8956bb625663713503b95ad8e5917bd294744/examples/webgl_loader_3ds.html#L47-L49. It's a different loader but the approach should be the same.

Comment: My problem was not solved at all. The loader looks complicated enough to manipulate.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your asset (with textures)? I can then try to load in on my system.

Comment: No matter what model I use, the result is the same. I have also seen tons of the same problem on other threads.

Comment: The 404 error should provide the URL which lead to the 404. If you copy and paste that URL into the browser, is the asset provided?

Comment: @Radio : I have to admit I have not properly replied you the first time because you didn't get what I meant at the first place. So I write this for more clarification. The url of the error prone texture is not working in the browser, and of course it is the stem of all the problems. The thing is that I cannot program the model in order to make the loader check the texture folder. Whatever I do, it will only check the folder in which the .js file is located in. As I said earlier, it is a known problem of the loader.